# call object while method non-static in java

Tags: java

I have a problem, I didn't test it with this line of code, but I know it is going to happen. So my problem is I need to code like a receipt, but with a object. So and I used the constructor to do this but when I'm going to call the method "auswahl" where I want to define, that the next receipt being created or not. So when I call the method "auswahl" it's non static, but in order to use objects properly I cant use static right? So how do I solve this problem?

Sorry for the comments being in german, I visit a german University

```
import java.util.*;
class Beleg{

    int belegNummer;
    int stellenZeiger;
    int betrag;

    public Beleg(int n)
    {
        //Konstrukor, welcher den Beleg als objekt erstellt.
        System.out.println("Ihre Belegnummer lautet: "+n);
    }









    public int auswahl()
    {
        //in dieser methde werden die daten des Kassenzettels gespeichert
        //sie werden auch automatisch hochgezählt un dem Objekt übergeben.
        //ab 10000 werden Belegnummern verteilt
    }




    public static void main(String []args)
    {
    }
}
```

Let me just say that this program is incomplete, just beacause I know what is going to happen but I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your main method into another class and create inside it an object of your class Beleg. Then you can access your method auswahl with instanceOfBeleg.auswahl();

Comment: ok, thank you I'll try that !

Comment: It doesn't need to be in another class.

Comment: ok, then how can I also do that wihtout moving it into another class? @Nand

Comment: @Nand that doesn't work it tells me "the constructor connot be applied to given types" and I literally do not know what it means/where it is coming from

Comment: You need to provide the "n" with the `new Beleg()`, example `new Beleg(4)`.

Comment: @Nand well thank you anyways I just started my first semester, thats why im asking.